# What does a recursive function return if it does not have a return statement?

Tags: c, recursion, return

What does a recursive function return if it does not have a return statement in a separate sentence.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rec(int i)
{
    if (i != 3) 
        return rec(++i);
}

int main()
{
    rec(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will run infinitive as `i` will always be unequal to 3

Comment: It will occur an infinite loop.

Comment: Not infinite, just recursive over both *positive* and then *negative* ranges of `int` before reaching `3` (with a pinch of overflow in between).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and signed overflow is UB. :)

Comment: Yep, that pinch hurts.

Comment: It often returns a warning about 'not all paths return a value'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [C documentation on return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return):

> Reaching the end of any other value-returning function is undefined behavior, but only if the result of the function is used in an expression.

So the behavior is undefined if any function that is supposed to return a value but doesn't return a value and when we try to use that returned value. On most implementation it returns a garbage.

For your case you are not using the return value so it has no effect here. Also you will get an infinite recursion since first call has 5 and it is incremented in later calls.

Comment: Any quotes to support that? If the function call return call is used, I agree. but wha if the return value is not used?

Comment: @SouravGhosh added a reference. I missed the point before that it is only UB if we try to use that value. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Well, then, dont you think, at first sight this answer is wrong? It points to soemthing which is not applicable in this case?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, I agree that first version of my answer was wrong. That's why edited it.

Comment: I am talking about the current version. Your answer emphasize on something which is correct but not relevant here. You need to rephrase it (or remove it altogether)

Comment: "What does a recursive function return if it does not have a return statement in a separate sentence" - I'm not sure why are you thinking that this is not relevant. OP directly asked a general question.

Answer (score 2):

See the [C11 standard](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.9.1p12), *§6.9.1 [Function definitions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12)* :

> *12   If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.*

Thus if you got a function that ought to return a value, it might not return a value. But if the function does not return a value but the calling code tries to use the return value of the function afterwards, the behaviour is undefined.
It's irrelevant whether the function is used recursively or not.

Answer (score 1):

If non-void function without evaluating a return statement, then behaviour is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

According to [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return):

> Reaching the end of a function other than main is equivalent to
>   return;. For main, see main function. **Reaching the end of any other
>   value-returning function is undefined behavior, but only if the result
>   of the function is used in an expression.**

**C Standard, 5.1.2.2.3, paragraph 1 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011]:**

> "Reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of
>   0." As a result, it is permissible for control to reach the end of the main() function without executing a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointer out it is undefined behavior. Doubly so for the integer overflow. Here is what gcc makes out of the function on x86_64 (when you ignore the warning):

```
0000000000000000 <rec>:
   0:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

It simply returns with whatever value happens to be in the return register.

Other perfectly valid results would be formating your harddrive or selling your soul to the devil. I hope clang would turn this in an #ub2 opcode but can't test this atm.

Comment: In accordance with the recent C standard, It ought to be undefined behaviour only if you actually read the return value - see my answer...

Comment: The signed integer overflow should remain even if you don't use the result. It is undefined if the function ever returns when called with values greater than 3.